# filtering files from search

Tags: shell-script, aix

I have some files containing date and timestamp which I want to exclude from the output of `ls` as in:

```
 test.log.15-05-25_20:41:05.20150611
 test.log.15-05-27_20:28:32.20150611
 test.log.15-05-26_20:29:40.20150611
 test.log.
 test-file~df_gp~1.log.
 test.log.20150616
 test.log.15-05-28_20:28:27.20150616
 test.log.15-05-27_20:28:32.20150616
 test.log.15-05-26_20:29:40.20150616
 test.log.15-05-25_20:41:05.20150616
 test-bat-test.log.
```

and the output should only list the below files meaning any file containing a date and timestamp should be omitted

```
 test.log.
 test-file~df_gp~1.log.
 test-bat-test.log.
```

Is there a way in which this can be done?

Comment: Is `ls` a requirement or would `find` file listing be ok?

Comment: find will also do as long as the files with the above date and time suffix are excluded

Comment: `find . -type f ! -name 'test.log.[0-9][0-9]*'`

Answer (score 1):

You could use GNU `find` :

```
 find * -regextype posix-extended \! -regex '.*[0-9]{8}.*' -prune
```

If the date is always at the end of the string, and preceded by a `.`, you could also use the regex `.*\.[0-9]{8}` which would reflect that and reduce the risk of wrongly excluded files.

**How it works :**

- `-regextype posix-extended` selects a type of regex suitable for the regex below
- `\!` negates the meaning of the statement that follows it
- `-regex '.*[0-9]{8}.*'` matches any file that has eight consecutive digits (ie a date of  the form `20150616`)
- `-prune` prevents `find` from listing the sub directories

**Other option :**

- Add the `-f` option to only list files

**EDIT:**

On AIX with no support for regular expression in `find`, you could use the following (using the standard globing mechanism) :

```
find * \! -name '*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*' -prune
```

Or, if the date is always at the end of the string, and preceded by a `.`, the following pattern can be used : `*.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`

**EDIT 2:**

If you want the files to begin with `test`, you could use :

```
find * -prune -type f \! -name 'test*.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

If you don't want to use the filename expansion by the shell and don't have additional directory in that directory, you could also use :

```
find . -type f \! -name 'test*.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: I am getting find: bad option -regextype error. Please can you suggest how to fit this for the example I've shown? I am running this on AIX

Comment: Oh... AFAIK, `find` on AIX doesn't support regex at all...

Comment: @user68112 : Edited with a new solution with that in mind

Comment: so how do I use this in my example where all filenames start with 'test' in the current directory, have other names in between like  test.log. or  test-file~df_gp~1.log. or  test-bat-test.log. but all ending with a date preceded by a . as you rightly said. Am new to this usage

Comment: @user68112 `find * -prune -type f \! -name 'test*.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: @user68112 Or, if you don't want to use the filename expansion by the shell and don't have additional directory in that directory, you could simply use `find . -type f \! -name 'test*.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`

Comment: your previous example with prune is closer to what I am looking for and the files with date and time are excluded this time but the output is listing all files but only those that are beginning with test is what should show up

Comment: @user68112 Both examples in the comments preceding yours should do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use `| grep -v` to filter out lines I do not want.
If the grep does not remove enough, I add another one:

```
$ ls | grep -v 2015 |grep -v 2014
```

This is easier than having to remember regex posix parameters for find :)

Comment: You could also add patterns using the `-e` option of `grep` and use one instance to rule all your patterns. ;)